# How to save performance when ranking elements following a third dimension

Tags: c#, performance, canvas

I am developing a Winform program which draws various shapes on a Canvas.

My next step would be to add a 'Z' property to these shapes to be able to determine which one is on top or under the other when some of them occupy a common space.

There are two cases when this differentiation is useful: when the user select a space with two or more shapes, and when they are painted.

These shapes are stored in a `IBindingList` collection, so it has an `ApplySort` method which made my first idea:
 sort the shapes according to their Z property, paint them in increasing order and select them in decreasing order.

Unfortunately this is causing performance degradation issue when my collection is modified multiple times in a short time span ( when scrolling my view over the entire canvas, or when zooming ) so I am looking for a different way to sort my shapes.

So far I am exploring to other possibilities:

- Never sort them and just make a comparison when there is an intersection, but this would force me to check every time the canvas is repainted.
- Having an already sorted collection, associating Z level and a collection of shapes belonging to this level, this way I would just have to check on which level does a shape rely and paint them in the order of the main collection.

Do you think I am going in the right direction? Or is there a way to avoid permanent sorting of all elements on screen?

Comment: You only need to re-sort whenever you add or remove an item, right? When zooming / moving your view, the Z-index won't change.

Comment: Yes, but I keep an shorten collection inside the view representing the visible shapes, to perform some operations on a smaller amount of objects. So I have to update this collection when I move / zoom the view, especially if the scrolling is fast, sorted state makes it way less fluent.